# How to use the event handler onEditCommit and onEditCancel on JavaFX 2?

Tags: listview, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I'm trying  to make a `ListView` **editable**, but when I add the event handlers `onEditCommit` and `onEditCancel` in the code I can't change the text in the `ListView`. Below my code (executed but the **edit** doesn’t work):

```
public class ItensTipoStringController implements Initializable {
   @FXML
   private ListView lstItens;
   ArrayList<String> itens = new ArrayList<>();
   ObservableList itensObservaveis = FXCollections.observableArrayList(itens);

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 
      itens.add("Evandro");
      itens.add("Miguel");

      lstItens.setEditable(true);        
      lstItens.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
      lstItens.getItems().addAll(itens);

      lstItens.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            System.out.println("onEditCommit");
        }
    });

    lstItens.setOnEditCancel(new EventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            System.out.println("onEditCancel");
        }
    });

    lstItens.setOnEditStart(new EventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            System.out.println("onEditStart");
        }
    });
   }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "can't change text"?

Answer (score 6):

> the edit doesn’t work

You mean that the value of list item didn’t change on the `OnEditCommit` ?

Of course, you are just printing `System.out.println("onEditCommit");`

You have to update your item, add this line to your `handle` method body.

```
lstItens.getItems().set(event.getIndex(), event.getNewValue());
```

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/tarrsalah/5492452) provides a complete working example, you can find more informations about `JavaFX ListView` [here](http://fxexperience.com/2012/05/listview-custom-cell-factories-and-context-menus/) and  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm).

Comment: System.out.println commands are just to verify if event handlers were running. My problem is when I run the application. I can beginning edit an item by double click, but when I press the enter button the item is not changed. Removing event handlers I can edit an item normally.

Comment: Problem solved tarrsalah! The gist's link help me. Just for comment, I'm used Scene Builder for create FXML files and it's have some bugs to update FXML. The event handler was not being inserted in the XML file. Now I see this problem and solved it. Thanks tarrsalah!