# Editable JavaFX ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'd like to make an editable listView. The documentation indicates that simply setting editable=true is insufficient, and I wasn't able to find an example anywhere.

In my FXML I have:

```
<ListView fx:id="queueListView" editable="true"/>
```

What else do I need (in the FXML or in my controller) to make this happen?

Comment: Did you look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300090/how-to-use-the-event-handler-oneditcommit-and-oneditcancel-on-javafx-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300090/how-to-use-the-event-handler-oneditcommit-and-oneditcancel-on-javafx-2)?

Comment: Okay, looks like I have to set the cell factory to a textField, and that'd do it. Great, thank you!